# Evaluate dynamic column name inside update function in a T-SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to use a dynamic column name inside an Update Function in a T-SQL trigger.

In my table I have a column, "Last_Name".  Inside the trigger I'm able to evaluate

```
update(Last_Name)
```

but I'm not able to evaluate

```
DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(25)
SET @colName = 'Last_Name'
update(@colName)
```

Is there a way to get SQL Server to recognize the dynamic column name inside this trigger for the update function?

**Update:**

Inside the trigger definition I tried

```
DECLARE @dynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @dynamicSQL = 'IF(update(' + @colName + ')) 
BEGIN
    PRINT ''okay-' + @colName + '''   
END'

exec(@dynamicSQL);
```

but received the following error:

> Can only use IF UPDATE within a CREATE TRIGGER statement.

It looks like the "exec" statement is evaluating the dynamic SQL outside of the trigger itself.